# Just can't get this to work

Tags: php, javascript

I have been trying to figure out this problem I've been having all day.  I will give you a simplified run down of what I have been trying to do.  The user enters a number, and however much the number is, is the number of categories there are going to be on the following page.  Within each category, there is an input text button, along with an "Add Textbox" button that adds additional input textboxes dynamically.  However, the problem here is that each category has this same setup on the same page.  For example, if the user enters the number "3", then the page will vertically load three categories looking something like the following:

```
Category #1
(Initial user input textbox for category #1)
("Add Textbox" button to allow user to fill out another option)

Category #2
(Initial user input textbox for category #2)
("Add Textbox" button to allow user to fill out another option)

Category #3
(Initial user input textbox for category #3)
("Add Textbox" button to allow user to fill out another option)
```

The struggle I have been encountering is that each category button will need to have its own function, to tell the button where to place the textbox.  This coupled with the fact that the number of categories changes depending on the user's input, has made things difficult.  I started with the following:

```
var categoryCount = <?php echo $categoryCount; ?>;
var click = {};

for (var num=1;num<=categoryCount;num++) {
    var newClick = "click_" + num;
    click[newClick] = function() { 
        // some contents when this button is clicked 
    };
}
```

This JS creates an object of functions, which in JS would be able to be accessed by doing something like the following:

```
click['click_' + someID]();
```

However, the problem is that I cannot do this using the "onclick" attribute in my HTML/PHP button.  I cannot access this object of functions, and cannot call any of the individual functions, obviously.  I think I am going to need to rethink all of this and start again.  I just can't think of another way to get this to work.  Please share your ideas with me!  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can pass an explicit `this` context: `click['click_' + someID].call(element)` where `element` is `this`.

Comment: why you need a function for every created element?

Comment: please change the question title to something meaningful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?? Like whats the reason behind these buttons and functions...... because i am 100% sure there is a better way to do it, but i cant really help fully if i dont know EXACTLY what context you are wanting this to work in

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I'd write a constructor I could use like this

```
var cat1 = new Category(document.body);
```

Luckily for you, I also wrote one as an example. See the [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JdYWn/2/). I haven't styled it at all for the new lines etc, though.

```
var Category = (function () {
    var categoryCount = 0;
    function elem(tag) { // shortcut
        return document.createElement(tag);
    }
    function text(str) { // shortcut
        return document.createTextNode(str);
    }
    function Category(node) {
        var self = this; // this should have been var'd, oops!!
        this.categoryId = ++categoryCount;
        // make add button
        this.addButton = elem('button');
        this.addButton.appendChild(text('Add Textbox'));
        this.addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            self.addTextbox();
        });
        // make wrapper
        this.wrapper = elem('section');
        this.wrapper.setAttribute('id', 'cat'+this.categoryId);
        this.wrapper.appendChild(this.addButton);
        // make textboxes
        this.textboxes = [];
        this.addTextbox();
        // append to document
        if (node) {
            this.append(node);
        }
    }
    Category.prototype.addTextbox = function () {
        var e = elem('textarea');
        e.setAttribute('name', 'cat-'+this.categoryId+'-textbox[]');
        this.textboxes.push(e);
        this.wrapper.insertBefore(e, this.addButton);
    };
    Category.prototype.append = function (node) {
        return node.appendChild(this.wrapper);
    };
    return Category;
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  This is a clever idea.  I updated the jsfiddle, trying to implement two categories, but it doesn't seem to be working properly when adding textboxes for each category.  Check it out:  http://jsfiddle.net/JdYWn/1/

Comment: @Jess a classic case of forgetting to `var` on my part, sorry. Fixed answer now (see edit)

Comment: Wow, this is really wonderful!  Thanks so much.  I just have one little problem.  Right now, I have my JS code in a .js file.  I've already implemented part of my form in this file.  In my main PHP file, I am simply doing a <script type="text/javascript" src="js/categories.js"></script> and then later calling all of the form together.  However, even though the form is submitting, it seems that for some reason the textboxes are not posting any data.  I will make a fiddle really quickly.

Comment: Take note of the _name_ of the `<textarea>`s, `cat-'+this.categoryId+'-textbox[]`, ie. `cat-1-textbox[]` etc. In _PHP_ you would `$_POST['cat-1-textbox'][0]`, `$_POST['cat-1-textbox'][1]`, etc.. If not `isset($_POST['cat-1-textbox'])` then maybe hyphens are not permitted? I threw them in for visibility

Comment: Also, it may be where you're appending them - `document.body` is directly to `<body>`, not within your `<form>`.